# Rails wants pg 0.10.0 but I can only install pg 0.10.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm on Mac OS X. If I run `sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install pg`, it works just fine. However, I get this error when I try to visit my Rails project in the browser:

```
Could not find pg-0.10.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

If I then uninstall 0.10.1 and try to install 0.10.0, I get this:

```
$ sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" gem install pg --version 0.10.0
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Ruby cflags: "-arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common  "
MacOS X build: fixing architecture flags:
  using the value in ARCHFLAGS environment variable ("-arch i386").
  finding flags common to both Ruby and PostgreSQL...
  testing for architecture: "ppc"
  testing for architecture: "i386"
  common arch flags: -arch i386
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.10.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.10.0/ext/gem_make.out
```

I don't care whether I find a way to make Rails accept pg 0.10.1 or if I find a way to install pg 0.10.0, but I need to do one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is version 0.10.0 listed in your `Gemfile.lock`? If so, you should be able to update the version Rails is looking for by running `bundle update pg`, assuming your `Gemfile` doesn't also specify version 0.10.0.